# Open close <ul> after every 2 records?

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
 for ($i = 0; $i < count($listings); $i++)
    {
                if ($i != 0 && $i%2 == 0)
                   {
                      $endul .= $arr[$i] . '</ul> <hr /> <ul class="listing">';
                   }
                   else
                   {
                      $endul .= $arr[$i];
                   }
```

And am trying to close a  after 2 records and then re-open for the next 2 records, etc... So far it seems like the code is working "somewhat" properly BUT it's taking the first 3 records and then closing the UL and not just the first 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, 0 is the first record and your if statement excludes it specifically. So it won't close until after the third record, which is $i = 2.

Example:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++) {
    if ($i % 2 == 0) {
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
```

This works fine for me.

Comment: when i changed it, it closed the <ul> every record ;(

Comment: doesnt cloe the <ul> until record #4 now ??

Comment: I've edited my response. The code here is minimal and works. If it doesn't work, something is wrong elsewhere.

Comment: i took your if statement inside and that worked???  hmm, not sure why but it did! :)

Answer (score 2):

This is my first StackOverflow post so bear with me :)

The problem is with this condition here:

```
if ($i != 0 && $i%2 == 0)
```

If you trace the values of $i as you go through the loop, you'll get the following:

```
$i = 0 ==> false
$i = 1 ==> false
$i = 2 ==> true
$i = 3 ==> false
$i = 4 ==> true
```

So it's printing out

```
    $arr[0] .
    $arr[1] .
    $arr[2] . '</ul> <hr /> <ul class="listing">' .
    $arr[3] .
    $arr[4] . '</ul> <hr /> <ul class="listing">'
```

In order to solve this problem, you need to change the if condition

```
if ($i%1 == 1)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can try grouping them in chunk first

```
$group = 2;
$listings = range("A", "Z");

foreach ( array_chunk($listings, 2) as $set ) {
    printf('<ul class="listing">%s</ul>', implode(array_map(function ($v) {
        return sprintf('<li>%s</li>', $v);
    }, $set)));
}
```

Or

```
foreach ( array_chunk($listings, 2) as $set ) {
    printf('<ul class="listing">');
    foreach ( $set as $v ) {
        printf('<li>%s</li>', $v);
    }
    printf('</ul>');
}
```

You would get same result

```
<ul class="listing">
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
</ul>
<ul class="listing">
    <li>C</li>
    <li>D</li>
</ul>
<ul class="listing">
    <li>E</li>
    <li>F</li>
</ul>
<ul class="listing">
    <li>G</li>
    <li>H</li>
</ul>
<ul class="listing">
    <li>I</li>
    <li>J</li>
</ul>

 .......
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
$endul .= $arr[$i] . '</ul> <hr /> <ul class="listing">';
```

To this:

```
$endul .= '</ul> <hr /> <ul class="listing">'.$arr[$i];
```

Comment: Giving me the same 3 records first :(

Comment: Are you iterating over the right array? In the for loop condition you are using `$listings`, but inside the loop you are using `$arr`. Can you post example contents of those two arrays?

Answer (score 0):

This is Perl or PHP, right?  Maybe tag it with those languages in the future?  Anyway, I suspect your problem is that your array begins with a zero index.

I'm speculating, but let's assume your @arr array contains elements with HTML markup

```
<li>whatever</li>
```

line items.

Let's count up your elements:

Element 0 - Do I pass the test? No: add first line item, but don't add close, rule and open.

Element 1 - Do I pass the test? No: add a second line item, but don't add close, rule and open.

Element 2 - Do I pass the test? Yes: add the third line item, and then add close, rule and open.

Element 3 - Do I pass the test? No: add new first line item, but don't add close, rule and open.

Element 4 - Do I pass the test? Yes: add new second line item, and then add close, rule and open.

Element 5 - You know the pattern: we repeat with groups of two line items before closing.

Because this code starts with zero, we have the extra case with zero and two in the first group of items.

The modulus of the index could test for odd instead of even:

```
if ($i%2 == 1)
```

And I think that test would build the format the way you want, where you'd add the "record close" markup after each odd element.  I'm assuming you have to logic outside of the loop to do the final close markup.  Of course you're still going to have an extra empty unordered list container in the case of the final element being odd, but maybe add something for that?

Answer (score 0):

This is the best approach:

```
    $rows = range(1,10);
        $i=1;
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach($rows as $key=>$row)
        {
            echo "<li>$row</li>";
            if($i%2==0)
            {
              echo "</ul><ul>"; 
            }
            $i++;
        }
       echo "</ul>";
```